# How is a message queue implemented in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I would like to know how Message Queues are implemented in the Linux Kernel.

Comment: IPC_NOWAIT we use it only in the reciever

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Linux kernel (2.6) implements two message queues:
<sub>(rather 'message lists', as the implementation is done by using a linked list not strictly following the FIFO principle)</sub>

**System V IPC messages**

The message queue from System V.

A process can invoke `msgsnd()` to send a message. He needs to pass the IPC identifier of the receiving message queue, the size of the message and a message structure, including the message type and text.

On the other side, a process invokes `msgrcv()` to receive a message, passing the IPC identifier of the message queue, where the message should get stored, the size and a value *t*.

*t* specifies the message returned from the queue, a positive value means the first message with its type equal to *t* is returned, a negative value returns the last message equal to type *t* and zero returns the first message of the queue.

Those functions are defined in [include/linux/msg.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/msg.h) and implemented in [ipc/msg.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/ipc/msg.c)

There are limitations upon the size of a message (max), the total number of messages (mni) and the total size of all messages in the queue (mnb):

```
$ sysctl kernel.msg{max,mni,mnb}
kernel.msgmax = 8192
kernel.msgmni = 1655
kernel.msgmnb = 16384
```

The output above is from a Ubuntu 10.10 system, the defaults are defined in [msg.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/msg.h).

More incredibly old System V message queue stuff explained [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node27.html).

**POSIX Message Queue**

The POSIX standard defines a message queue mechanism based on System V IPC's message queue, extending it by some functionalities:

- Simple file-based interface to the application
- Support for message priorities
- Support for asynchronous notification
- Timeouts for blocking operations

See [ipc/mqueue.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/ipc/mqueue.c)

**Example**

`util-linux` provides some programs for analyzing and modifying message queues and the POSIX specification gives some C examples:

Create a message queue with `ipcmk`; generally you would do this by calling C functions like `ftok()` and `msgget()`:

```
$ ipcmk -Q
```

Lets see what happened by using `ipcs` or with a `cat /proc/sysvipc/msg`:

```
$ ipcs -q

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
0x33ec1686 65536      user       644        0            0
```

Now fill the queue with some messages:

```
$ cat <<EOF >msg_send.c
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/msg.h> 

int main() {
  int msqid = 65536;
  struct message {
    long type;
    char text[20];
  } msg;

  msg.type = 1;
  strcpy(msg.text, "This is message 1");
  msgsnd(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), IPC_NOWAIT);
  strcpy(msg.text, "This is message 2");
  msgsnd(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), IPC_NOWAIT);

  return 0;
}
EOF
```

Again, you generally do not hardcode the msqid in the code.

```
$ gcc -o msg_send msg_send.c
$ ./msg_send
$ ipcs -q

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
0x33ec1686 65536      user       644        40           2
```

And the other side, which will be receiving the messages:

```
$ cat <<EOF >msg_recv.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int main() {
  int msqid = 65536;
  struct message {
    long type;
    char text[20];
  } msg;
  long msgtyp = 0;

  msgrcv(msqid, (void *) &msg, sizeof(msg.text), msgtyp, MSG_NOERROR | IPC_NOWAIT);
  printf("%s \n", msg.text);

  return 0;
}
EOF
```

See what happens:

```
$ gcc -o msg_recv msg_recv.c
$ ./msg_recv
This is message 1
$ ./msg_recv
This is message 2
$ ipcs -q

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
0x33ec1686 65536      user       644        0            0
```

After two receives, the queue is empty again.

Remove it afterwards by specifying the key (`-Q`) or msqid (`-q`):

```
$ ipcrm -q 65536
```

Comment: So does the message (type and text) get cloned/copied and then that copy gets put into the system's message queue?

Comment: very nicely put. Thank you for this amazing explanation.